# How to count rows that match multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a macro to count how many rows match some criteria.

In this example, the macros needs to be able to count where `column2` is `A` or `B` and where `column3` is `X` or `W`:

```
column1 column2 column3  
name1   A       X  
name2   B       X  
name3   A       W  
name4   C       X  
name5   A       Z  
name6   C       X  
name7   B       W
```

It should return `4`, as `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, `name7` are matching.

I have tried with `COUNTIFS` and array formulas but it seems that it's not possible without VBA.

Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't name3 also be counted?

Comment: COUNTIFS should do what you want.

Comment: @Kubie Good catch, i edited the post.

Comment: In this specific case, this formula should work for you: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B2:B8,"A",C2:C8,{"X","W"})+COUNTIFS(B2:B8,"B",C2:C8,{"X","W"}))`  Is there a specific reason you need VBA?

Comment: @tigeravatar - I am guessing VBA just because this isn't a straightforward `COUNTIFS()`, so they assumed it was not easily done.

Comment: @tigeravatar do you really need `SUMPRODUCT`? Isn't `SUM` already enough? `=SUM(COUNTIFS(B:B,"A",C:C,{"X","W"})+COUNTIFS(B:B,"B",C:C,{"X","W"}))` also returns 4

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yeah, you could do it with `SUM` :)

Comment: @tigeravatar can't you do two arrays in a countifs: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B:B,{"A";"B"},C:C,{"X","W"}))`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ SUM works when using actual values in the array but will not work if the array is replaced with a range.

Comment: @ScottCraner Very clever, I hadn't considered that, but yes that absolutely works :)

Comment: @ScottCraner - Is it just a typo you have a `;` in there?

Comment: @BruceWayne no, when using two arrays(which is the max) one must be horizontal and the other vertical.

Comment: @ScottCraner - And the `;` does that for arrays? (Can you perhaps put that in an answer, and explain a little? I don't recall seeing that used like that before and it's pretty neat)

Comment: @BruceWayne have a look here: https://exceljet.net/formula/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

Comment: The OP asked for vba, and has not clarified that Functions would be a viable answer.  But when creating an array `{}` the `,` is horizontal break and the `;` is the vertical break.  Highlight a range that is 2x2, put this in the formula bar: `={1,2;3,4}` and hit Ctrl Shift Enter. @BruceWayne

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner and Pᴇʜ! :D

Comment: I dont need VBA if it can be done without, i thought that it was not possible with countifs, sorry for the confusion.  
I will look into your solution, thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible without VBA using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($B$2:$B$8="A")+($B$2:$B$8="B"))*(($C$2:$C$8="X")+ 
($C$2:$C$8="W")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i tried this formula before, but it was not working.   
`=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8;{"A";"B"})*($C$2:$C$8;{"X";"W"}))`

Comment: @Gokh It didn't work because one of the array separators **must** be a `,` while the other is a `;`! You used two times `;` which doesn't work. Read all the comments for clarification. Other Excel language versions use `.` and `;` as array separators. Depends on your Excel localization.

Comment: @Gokh just to explain the differences between the formula.  This one as written will iterate 28 times adding 4 iterations per line added to the data set. My formula will only iterate 4 times no matter the number of rows added to the data set.  While with a small data set one will not notice the difference in calc times, Large data sets will be slower with this formula.

Answer (score 5):

Use this Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(B:B,{"A";"B"},C:C,{"X","W"}))
```

COUNTIFS can use Arrays, If more that one(two is the max) one must be Horizontal(using `,`) and the other vertical(using `;`)

One can use SUM() instead of SUMPRODUCT in this specific case, but if the arrays are replaced by ranges:

1. If two Ranges one must be vertical and the other Horizontal.  This can be accomplished by physically making the range that way or using TRANSPOSE() on one.
2. If SUM() is used with a range it must be Array entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.